# SEO влияют ли плохие слова (маты) на индексацию сайта?

Tags: seo

Стоит вопрос, поставить ли запрет на сообщения с матами. Причины сделать это, мысль о том что если пользователи будут писать мат, страница будет ниже в ПС, так ли это?

Comment: @Владимир ваше личное отношение к мату как к явлению не имеет отношения к вопросу.